# Unity3d Error: "String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters."

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I keep getting this Error With no StackTrace:

> "String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters."

did anyone else face this in Unity3d version 5.0.2f1 ?

should i care about it or just ignore it?

Comment: You should care about it because apparently a string you're trying to display in a Text component is too long.

Comment: Whats the solution? As i don't know which object with Text Component is causing it.

Comment: Go through your text components in your hierarchy and see if you can find the culprit.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. However if I have two TextGenerators side by side, only one of them will display this error, while the other will not. The error also pops up intermittently, it is not a consistent number of characters before this happens. It may happen after a few hundred, then again after a few thousand.