# "String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters." when doing Regex.Replace - Unity C#

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

When executing

```
newstring = Regex.Replace(oldString, oldSubString, newSubString);
```

I get the following errors:

> String too long for TextMeshGenerator. Cutting off characters.
>   count <= std::numeric_limits::max()

My string size is around 15000 characters and I am using **Unity 5.1.1f1 (64-bit)**

I have looked around for a solution but can´t find anything, any ideas or workarounds?

thanks!

Comment: You can't possibly get that error on Regex.Replace. The code you have provided must be incomplete.

Comment: I would consider it a bug in Unity3D. Update your Unity3D to the newest version, and if this problem persists you can inform them about it. They probably translate the C# code into the C++, hence this strange error message.

Comment: This [looks to be resolved](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/issues/37/string-too-long-for-textmeshgenerator). Maybe it is not resolved appropriately...

Comment: @stribizhev  I don´t follow what it is that they have done, seems like they are just taking a small substring our of the original?:        if(m_RenderedName.Length > 100)
    m_RenderedName = m_RenderedName.Substring(0, 100);
   m_RenderedName = m_RenderedName.Replace("\n", "");

Comment: @Santi: Yes, it seems they are just truncating the string. Not a good workaround, but perhaps, depending on your `oldSubString`, it can also be applied in your case.

Comment: @Mihai-AndreiDinculescu you are right, I don´t get the error from the Regex, I actually get it when I try to run GUILayout.Label (newString) after the replace. The  Regex.Replace is causing the string to go from roughly 10k to 15k characters and I am guessing thats too much for GuiLayout, although the error messages don't point to any specific line in the code and they appear 3 times each...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a Unity's Bug. But NOT SURE about it.

[See Here](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/issues/37/string-too-long-for-textmeshgenerator) for Explanation. I have already asked the same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205173/unity3d-error-string-too-long-for-textmeshgenerator-cutting-off-characters) and i guess it doesn't have anything to do with regex/

Comment: indeed it is not that the problem - as I understand it is an issue related to the ui Text component rendering to canvas that don't like to output strings too long.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround could be split your original string in two or more strings, apply the regex operation and finally join the partial strings. But possibly the bug will remain with 7.5k chars or similar.

Now, why do you want to use a Regex operation over an string of 15k chars?
Maybe if you describe you requirement the community can give you ideas of others ways to do the same job !

Comment: I need it to change the format of specific words inside a large text (eg bold, italics, etc...) like this:                                                         newstring = Regex.Replace(oldString, thisWordBold, </b>thisWordBold <b>),  GUI.Label(newstring). Splitting the string seems like the only alternative for the moment...

Comment: So you are able to split the large string without breaking a word, I mean, looking for space to split it., now, how many chars this version of buggy regex can handle, I don’t know.

Comment: So I don´t get the error from the Regex, I actually get it when I try to run GUILayout.Label (newString) after the replace. The Regex.Replace is causing the string to go from roughly 10k to 15k characters and I am guessing thats too much for GuiLayout.label, although the error messages don't point to any specific line in the code and they appear 3 times each...anyway, I will just split the string and render several labels, thanks